# HP 4250N printer rear bin issue

Tags: printer

I have a Dell running Windows 7 with an HP 4250N Printer. All of a sudden paper started exiting from the rear bin instead of the usual top bin. If rear door is closed, paper jams at the rear. There is no setting on the printer or in printer preferences to designate where paper exits. I have reinstalled the printer drivers, and cold started, but no change. Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

It's the rear output bin itself that controls where the paper exits: if it's open the paper will exit there, if it's closed the paper will go to the top output bin.

If the printer selects the rear output tray by itself, it probably means that an interlock switch has failed, so the printer always thinks it is open. That's also why it jams if you close the bin.

Have a look around inside the rear bin to see if you can spot the switch. The [service manual](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/473049/Hp-Laserjet-4250.html) does not show any electrical connections on the rear bin, so the switch is probably a little "flag" that interrupts a tiny optical sensor. You'll probably recognise the sensor when you see it - they're usually black and about 1 cm (say 1/2") in length. In this case the flag may just be a little "finger" near the hinge of the bin, which travels in and out of the sensor. Alternatively, the finger may press on a microswitch. The sensor/microswitch itself will be inside the printer.

You can also buy the entire assembly - but I do not think that is the problem. Googling showed me one for $26.89 .